# infinite scroll on a $rootScope variable for performance in ionic-list

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a `$rootScope` variable which consists of all my contacts, about 500 entries, when I tried to load them in list view inside a modal there is a delay in modal. Is there any way to use `infinite-scroll` on a variable which already have all data to increase performance.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="contact in $root.userContacts  track by $index">
    <label class="checkbox checkbox-energized">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
    {{contact.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I was thinking to load only 50 contacts at a time and update as the user scrolls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it using [`ion-infinite-scroll`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/).

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope, Contacts, $ionicModal) {
  $scope.contacts = Contacts.more();

  /**
   * Load more.
   */
  $scope.loadMore = function(){
    $scope.contacts = $scope.contacts.concat(Contacts.more());
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  };

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.openModal();
  });
});
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Contacts', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var contacts = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Ben Sparrow',
    lastText: 'You on your way?',
    face: 'img/ben.png'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max Lynx',
    lastText: 'Hey, it\'s me',
    face: 'img/max.png'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Adam Bradleyson',
    lastText: 'I should buy a boat',
    face: 'img/adam.jpg'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Perry Governor',
    lastText: 'Look at my mukluks!',
    face: 'img/perry.png'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mike Harrington',
    lastText: 'This is wicked good ice cream.',
    face: 'img/mike.png'
  }];

  return {
    /**
     * Generate fake contacts.
     */
    more: function() {
      var response = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        response.push(contacts[Math.floor(Math.random()*contacts.length)]);
      }
      return response;
    }
  };
});
```

**tab-contacts.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Contacts">
</ion-view>
<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">Contacts</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index" type="item-text-wrap">
            <img ng-src="{{contact.face}}">
            <h2>{{contact.name}}</h2>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-infinite-scroll
            on-infinite="loadMore()"
            distance="1%">
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

You can see a [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ioPAkW6hXkSOHhhqAUtt?p=preview).